# Eclipse logcat won't stop showing libEGL tags

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, logcat

My Eclipse logcat is going crazy showing 1000s of these libEGL tags. I have no idea what caused this. Does anyone know how to disable them or what could have caused them?

[image: Currently at 319,461 logs after running for 1 minute]